# IdenityServer3 windows auth support and custom grant flow support

Tags: windows-authentication, identityserver3

I am looking for IdentityServer3 version which can support windows authentication and customgrant.
I found the windows authentication version: "Windows Auth All-in-One" in github.
Windows token conversion is working fine.
But when I try to use custom grant flow, using the following code:

```
var client = new TokenClient(
                Constants.TokenEndpoint,
                "customclient",
                "secret");
return client.RequestCustomGrantAsync("custom", "read write", ParameterData).Result;
```

I am getting the response as:

> "error": "unsupported_grant_type"

Any idea how to enable the custom grant type in Windows Auth All-in-One version of Identity server?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please format your code to make it more readable, which will help others understand and answer your problem. Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2):

Using IdentityServer's extensibility mechanism, you can register a custom grant validator for the `my_custom_credential`.
The job of a custom grant validator is to validate the incoming data, and map that to an IdentityServer user.

You start by implementing this interface:

`public interface ICustomGrantValidator
{
    Task<CustomGrantValidationResult> ValidateAsync(ValidatedTokenRequest request);
    string GrantType { get; }
}`

In the `GrantType` property you specify which custom grant type you want to handle with this validator. 
In the ValidateAsync method you have access to the raw requests (e.g. for reading custom parameters like in the example
above) as well as validated data like scopes and client identity.

The result object allows you to set either a principal (with claims) that map to a user - or an error message.

You register the validator by setting it on the service factory:

`factory.CustomGrantValidators.Add( 
    new Registration<ICustomGrantValidator, MyCustomGrantValidator>());`

To use this grant type, you need to create a client with the following configuration:

- The `Flow` must be set to `Custom`
- The `AllowedCustomGrantTypes` must include the custom grant type

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/customGrantTypes.html